# Problems with text formats and Iframes

Tags: 7

I'm trying to display an iframe (google maps) on my node. I allowed "iframe" with the "plain text" format and unchecked "Display any HTML as plain text": http://www.diigo.com/item/image/fgah/3hc0?size=o

I select the text processing option  "Filtered text (user selects text format)" for the field:
http://www.diigo.com/item/image/fgah/dmeh?size=o
I enter the iframe code with the "plain text" selection 
http://www.diigo.com/item/image/fgah/7svw?size=o
The iframe renders fine.

I changed the text processing option for this field to "plain text": http://www.diigo.com/item/image/fgah/04e2?size=o

Now the iframe won't render (just shows the iframe HTML code).
Why would it not work, isn't it the same "plain text" option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each text format that you create has some different processing options.

If you select

> Display any HTML as plain text

Then the result is what you explained, where HTML code is escaped and displayed instead of having any effect.

Instead

> Limit allowed HTML tags

Can be used to limit the kind of html tags which are allowed, but if disallowed tags are used, they will not take effect.

It sounds like you are confusing the two.

**Update**

The text processing and input filters are not related.

You have filter called `plain text`, but you could call it anything, like `super input field`, `pony` or whatever. When you select filtered input, you get to choose which filter to use.

The other text formatting option is plain text. Selecting this means that you wont use **any** text filter, not even the one you might call `plain text`. The result of using this kind of text processor is that the text will be rendered as plain text.

Comment: Hi googletorp, sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I modified by question and added screenshots. Thansk for your help!

Comment: @uwe999 I updated my answer, hope this explains the difference between text processors and filters.